# Preventing ERC-721 mint through contract/script

Tags: ethereum, solidity

What is the best practice to force a user to mint through your website/preventing minting through contract on etherscan?

The only solution I've thought of is to require some merkle proof to mint which only the website knows, are there any other better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to restrict the mint to an authorized address, that only your website has a private key to.

Whenever the user makes some operation (e.g. payment to other predefined address), your website reacts to this by sending the mint transaction from the authorized address.